# Configure webpack to include node_modules as public source when needed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, jsx

I am new to webpack & react. I am using webpack 2.0. I have my webpack config as

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve("src"),
    entry: "index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve("build/js/"),
        publicPath: "/public/assets/js/",
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve("public")
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve("node_modules"), path.resolve("src")],
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: "url-loader", options:{ limit: 10000 } },
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

I need to be able to include node_modules in my index page to render some content I have defined as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>

<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="/node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

<!-- Main -->
<script src="/public/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me in configuring my webpack.config to throw in my node_modules when ever I need to expose them to the public page(s).

My folder structure is as

```
project
|-node_modules
|-src
 |-components
   |-Hello.tsx
 |-index.tsx
|-public
  |-index.html
|-webpack.config.js
|-package.json
```

Comment: you just want to include `react` and `react-dom` or any other lib also ?

Comment: I need to be able to include any of the js(s) from node_module.

Comment: want to ask one ques why u r putting `JSX` code inside `index.html` file? create a component put the code inside that, try not to include code in `index.html`.

Comment: my index.html does not have any code inside it. I tried to use https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html
and modified a little so that I can have my build out of my source control.

Comment: you can use `cdn` links for `react` and `react-dom`, as suggested in the link also you pasted.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that's not the way I want to go with.